# How to obtain the boundedness of $\{a_{n}\}_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\{a_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, a_{n} > 0$. Let also $k_{1}, k_{2} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $k_{1} > 0$ and $k_{2}\neq 0$. Assume $\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \bigg[k_{1}a_{n}^{2} - o(1)k_{2}a_{n} \bigg]<\infty$ exists. Show that $\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_{n}<\infty$!

My attempt so far is to use contradiction by assuming $\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_{n} = \infty$ so that I have
$$k_{1}\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_{n}^{2} - k_{2}\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}o(1)a_{n}<\infty$$But I don't know how to proceed to obtain the contradiction.

Remark : $o(1) \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Any help will be much appreciated!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove by contradiction. We are geiven that $k_1a_n^{2}-o(1)k_2a_n \leq M$ for all $n$ (for some $M <\infty)$. Hence $a_n[k_1a_n-o(1)k_2] \leq M$. If $(a_n)$ is not bounded there is a subsequence which tends to $\infty$. Can you get a contradiction now?.

Comment: I am sorry but I still cannot see where the contradiction occurs clearly. How to rigorously shows that $k_{1}a_{n} - o(1)k_{2} > 0$? Do you mean, by using $\varepsilon  = M > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n > N$ we have $a_{n} > M$?

Is this what you want to say?

Comment: @EvanWilliamChandra If $a_{n_i} \to \infty$ then $k_1a_{n_i}-o(1)k_2$ also tends to $\infty$ and the product tends to $\infty$.